# How to change a FTP password from Command Line?

Tags: ftp-client

I'm using putty to connect ftp server, available commands are listed above ;
Which one is for changing ftp password. Please help

```
ftp> help
Commands may be abbreviated.  Commands are:

!               cr              mdir            proxy           send
$               delete          mget            sendport        site
account         debug           mkdir           put             size
append          dir             mls             pwd             status
ascii           disconnect      mode            quit            struct
bell            form            modtime         quote           system
binary          get             mput            recv            sunique
bye             glob            newer           reget           tenex
case            hash            nmap            rstatus         trace
ccc             help            nlist           rhelp           type
cd              idle            ntrans          rename          user
cdup            image           open            reset           umask
chmod           lcd             passive         restart         verbose
clear           ls              private         rmdir           ?
close           macdef          prompt          runique
cprotect        mdelete         protect         safe
ftp>
```

Comment: I wouldn't classify this as a programming question. Maybe try superuser.com?

Comment: This is not a programatic question. should be asked in unix or superuser forum

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. You have to telnet to the server or use Remote Desktop.